# Set style for element if other element is hidden in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div (parent) that contains two children. I want to change color of first DIV if second DIV is hidden.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: block;">
     11111111
  </div>
  <div id="xyz" class="col-lg-6" style="display: none;">
     222222
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried something like:

```
.parent div:first-child:not(#xyz[hidden]) {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

but it doesn't work. So, is it possible in CSS3?

Comment: I think you need to use javascript on this one.

Comment: From what I know, it's possible only with JavaScript. Do you want an example?

Comment: I don't think its possible. CSS do not have logic ( conditions )

Comment: I know how to do with JavaScript :) But I'm trying with CSS.
So thank you for response :)

Comment: hidden is a attribute and can be used like you want in one way only. Only the second div can be targeted. here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/r7q4t40a/1/ please check hidden specs it might not suit your code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately your current HTML structure makes it impossible to target the first `<div>` with raw CSS.

However, if you **swap** the two elements, then you **can** target the visible div based on the visibility of `#xyz`:

```css
#xyz[style*='display: none'] ~ div {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="xyz" class="col-lg-6" style="display: none;">
    222222
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: block;">
    11111111
  </div>
</div>
```

The `~` selector targets any sibling `<div>` element where `#xyz` does not have a `style` of `display: none`. Unfortunately, although the `~` selects **siblings**, the siblings must come **after** the target div.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work the other way:

```css
div ~ #xyz[style*='display: none'] {
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: block;">
    11111111
  </div>
  <div id="xyz" class="col-lg-6" style="display: none;">
    222222
  </div>
</div>
```

You can stick with the current HTML structure if you use JavaScript though:

```js
if (document.getElementById('xyz').style.display = 'none') {
  document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].childNodes[1].style.background = '#00ff00';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: block;">
    11111111
  </div>
  <div id="xyz" class="col-lg-6" style="display: none;">
    222222
  </div>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="display: block;">
    11111111
  </div>
  <div id="xyz" class="col-lg-6" style="display: block;">
    222222
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yeees! Thank you dude :) It works for me. You save my time. Thank you again ;)