# How to show loading progress while wasm part being loaded (.NET 8, no pre-render)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor WASM standalone app it is easy, because there is dedicated element for that:

```html
<div id="app">Loading...</div>
```

And it gets replaced once the the app is loaded.

In Blazor on .NET 8 it is a different story. Consider these two pages:

```
@page "/home"
```

```
@page "/wasmPage"
@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false))
```

When transitioning from `/home` to `/wasmPage` Blazor removes the content of `<main>`, replace it with `bl-load` comment and starts loading the necessary files...

We have no element to show the `Loading...` message.

Is there anything to subscribe to?

Sources, I've discovered:

- Maybe the answer is hidden in [startup docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-8.0), it describes how to start the loading on my own, but that's not what I want to do..
- Once the loading process starts, the `--blazor-load-percentage` css variable appears. I can think of a solution with checking the presence, etc, but I hope there is a better way.
- [Editing loading scripts](https://stef-heyenrath.medium.com/show-a-loading-progress-indicator-for-a-blazor-webassembly-application-ea28595ff8c1) might be an options, but again - my hope is in a simpler solution.

After the discussion with `@MrC aka Shaun Curtis` it is obvious that the solution exists - using pre-rendered page. Basically placing the `Loading...` only when page is generated on the server (pre-rendered). ([similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653261/blazor-net-8-splash-screen)). That does not include my case when pre-render is set to false. I would still like to see if any solution exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I've set this as a duplicate question as I provided an answer to an extremely similar question a few hours ago - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653261  . Re-open if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis that is an interesting solution, but I think it wont help. I have disabled the prerender, thus I cannot use `IsPreRender` to place the splash screen. Or did I misunderstood how the package works?

Comment: Agreed, but why not enable Pre-Rendering?

Comment: Adds complexity. It is probably easy to handle (adding service also to the "server" project), but I removed the prerender to speed up development.  I will edit the question, I am still curious if any (non-prerender) solution exists.

Comment: Can you re-open the question @MrCakaShaunCurtis?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution, I'm encountering the same issue

Comment: @Lachevre I did, check the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figure out a good solution:

```html
<div class="[&>*:last-child:not(:first-child)]:hidden">
      @Body
    <div >
        Loading...
    </div>
</div>
```

It hides the last element (Loading...), but only when it isn't also the first element.

In other words: Shows the `Loading...`, until @Body is populated.

Comment: how come that there are css selector instead of class names in the class attribute, what kind of trick is this?

Comment: @somedotnetguy arbitrary properties and arbitrary variants of TailwindCSS https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties

Answer (score 2):

I was able to display a "Loading.." message while the WASM is downloading by doing the following:

Add a page in the server project that contains your "loading" text and the client side component.

```html
@page "/wasmPage"

<div id="loading-message">
  Loading...
</div>

<MyWasmComponent @rendermode=@(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false)) />
```

Add the following to MyWasmComponent.razor

```html
<script>
    function hideElementById(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Add the following to MyWasmComponent.razor.cs

```html
[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("hideElementById", "loading-message");
    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

As the "Loading..." is server side rendered, it will display as the WASM is downloading. Once the WASM is downloaded and rendered, it will find the element named "loading-message" and hide it.

Comment: Yes this will work, but it adds come code to the wasm part which I think should be avoided for such functionality.

Comment: For my application @Body is not only for WASM content. I also have static server-side rendered and InteractiveServer rendered content where I don't need or want to see any "Loading...".

Comment: this is not practical for "global" wasm apps

Answer (score 0):

To solve ther problem you need to:

1- Change the App.razor to be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorWebEnjaz.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="preload">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />

    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

 @code {
        [CascadingParameter]
        private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;
    
        private IComponentRenderMode LocalInteractiveWebAssemblyMode => new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(false);
    
        private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
            ? null
            : LocalInteractiveWebAssemblyMode;
    }
```

2- In "Routes.razor" in client application, add following style at the end of the page:

```
<style>
    #preload {
        display: none;
    }

</style>
```

This will show the progress when loading runtime files and when the app. start it hide it

**Note:** Any forced-relaod while calling NavigationManager.NavigateTo() function will show the progress then it will hide automatically again

Comment: But what if I have a page which isn't from wasm client project, but rather SSR? Then the `#preload` will be still shown, right?

Comment: No, only show when you back to wasm page and will hide automatically after wasm app loaded

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the answer of S Prez for use with a (Route) component, since I couldn't get his version to work with my usecase:

```html
<body>
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false)"/>
    <div class="even:hidden">
       Loading...
    </div>
</body>
```

When the page loads, the loading div is the only div, making it uneven (1). When the Route component loads, the loading div is uneven, thus making it hidden.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add a bit of JavaScript, just one function. Also note that this solution interacts with the DOM via JavaScript which is not really recommended, but at least its just removing 1 element, the pre loader.

In my App.razor file, this is the code there

```
<body>
    <!-- 1. Added this loader and styled it a bit.-->
    <div id="pre-loader" style="width: 100dvw; height: 100dvh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
        ...loading
    </div>
    <!-- ./-->

    <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveAutoRenderMode(false)" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>


    <!-- 2. Added this function below, when called it will remove the pre-loader element. 
        I call this from my main layout on after render method us jsruntime -->
    <script>
        function removePreLoader() {
            var preloader = document.getElementById("pre-loader");
            if (preloader) {
                preloader.remove();
                console.log("Pre loader removed");
            }
        }

         //updated so if the you are anywhere that includes "/account/" in the url,
         //e.g /account/login then the loader will be automatically removed.
        (function () {
            var current = window.location.href.toLowerCase(); 
            var res = current.includes('/account/');
            if(res){
                removePreLoader();
            }
         })();
    </script>
    <!-- ./-->
</body>
```

My MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

@* code omitted for brevity (remains the same) *@

@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        //This call then removes the loader. It doesn't matter how many times its called
        //because the javascript function checks if the emelent is still there or not
        await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("removePreLoader");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The concept is to show the banner when the WASM part is not under the DOM yet, but hide it (set the banner's `display` to `none`) when the main component is showing up in the DOM tree. so borrow the concept from [Set style for element if other element is hidden in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224530/set-style-for-element-if-other-element-is-hidden-in-css), we can achieve the following solution:

#### 1. Adding a banner next to WASM component.

In the host component, `MainLayout.razor` in your case, place a banner below the `@Body`:

```xml
<div class="page">
   @Body
   <div class="loading-banner">
      Loading....
   </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Tagging the WASM component

In your page using `InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode`, make sure adding a root element with class name set to `hide-loading-banner`:

```
@page "/wasmPage"
@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false))
<div class="hide-loading-banner">
  <!-- The rest of the page content here -->
</div>
```

#### 3. Adding a global CSS definition

Adding the following CSS definition in your style sheet, for example, `wwwroot/app.css`

```css
/* When an element with 'hide-loading-banner' class exists, 
   it will hide all sibling elements with 'loading-banner' class */
.hide-loading-banner ~ .loading-banner {
    display: none;
}
```

#### 4. Reference the new style sheet in your `App.razor` if not already.

#### 5. Profit.

So the logic is here:

Before the WASM part is loaded, there is no element with `hide-loading-banner` class under the root component, and the new CSS rule does not apply. The banner will be displayed.

After the WASM is added to the DOM tree, the new CSS rule applies as there is an element with `hide-loading-banner` class inside the hosting element, and one or more sibling element with 'loading-banner' class inside the same hosting element. the elements with `loading-banner` class are now being targeted by the new CSS rule, setting the `display` property to `none`, effectively been hidden.

Comment: That is an interesting solution, unfortunately it requires to add the `hide-loading-banner` inside every page, which is not highly practical..

Comment: Do you have hundreds of pages need to update? You must have some common root style / root element in each of your page you can leverage, to in place of the `.hide-loading-banner` css class .

Comment: I don't. It just adds complexity which wasn't necessary in previous version. That's why I consider this suboptimal solution.